# PHP - using array values in email message

Tags: php, arrays, email, variables

I'm using a script to create an email message, but for some reason, it can't read the variables...
Now, this isnt ordinary php syntax, because in the example I got it from, they used code like this:

```
$messageproper =
"New message:\n" .
" \n" .
"Full name: $fullname\n" .
"Email: $email\n" ;
```

Now, I tried this:

```
$messageproper =
    "New placed order:\n".
    "\n".
    "Ticket type: $orderdata['tickettype']\n".
    "From: $orderdata['from']\n".
    "To: $orderdata['to']\n";
```

But for some reason it gives errors in every line.
So I tried this:

```
 $messageproper =
    "New placed order:\n".
    "\n".
    "Ticket type: ".$orderdata['tickettype']."\n".
    "From: ".$orderdata['from']."\n".
    "To: ".$orderdata['to']."\n";
```

But for some reason that just leaves every variable empty.

Because Im using a function processOrder() (where I declare and set all the variables) and sendOrder() (where I assemble the email), I already tried making the $orderdata array global, but that didn't work either.

This is the important part of the script that sends the email:

```
$content_type = (!isset( $use_utf8 ) || ($use_utf8 == 0)) ? 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1"' : 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"' ;
$headersep = (!isset( $uself ) || ($uself == 0)) ? "\r\n" : "\n" ;
// ---------------------------- preparing the headers ----------------------------
$headers =
"From: \"$fullname\" <$email>" . $headersep . "Reply-To: \"$fullname\" <$email>" . $headersep . "X-Mailer: chfeedback.php 2.15.0" .
$headersep . 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . $headersep . $content_type ;

// ---------------------------- sending the email ----------------------------
if ($use_envsender) {
mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers, $envsender );
}
else {
    mail($mailto, $subject, $messageproper, $headers );
}
header( "Location: $thankyouurl" );
exit ;
```

**What could I be doing wrong here?
Also, could someone explain to me what kind of syntax this is, for the $messageproper ?** I've never seen such unlogic syntax before (however, now I think of it, I do: in MySQL queries, where you put a php variable in the request.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for using it inside string, use `{$orderdata['tickettype']}` instead of `$orderdata['tickettype']`. As for concatenating not working, check if you have your data defined in scope. (put `global $orderdata;` in both functions).

Comment: Oh damn, I forgot global in the second function!
But what kind of syntax is this, why doesnt it work like regular php syntax?

Comment: Leaving its merits aside, it *is* a regular php syntax.

Comment: Hmmm, ok, Let me refrase my question: why do I need to put the strings within the quotes, when I would normally do it like this: `"this is:".$string` when I now use `"this is $string"`?

Comment: Also, I placed curly brackets around all the variables now, but still It returns empty...

Comment: Well, how would it now if `['tickettype']` is a part of your variable or not? hence curly braces.
Now that it doesn't work, have you checked if the value is there, for instance, when you use the `.` concatenation?

Comment: Yeah, I tried using `echo '<script language="javascript">alert("'.$orderdata['mainpassenger']['dateday'].'");</script>';` But for some reason that sends an empty message, and gives me this error: `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...`

Comment: Well, if you have no data in your variable, no syntax will put it there, check your logic. The warning is because you have no output buffering and output this alert before setting some `header` elsewhere.

Comment: Yep, I found the header issue, because the function was complete, I sends me to a THank YOu page. And I found why all the variables returned empty... I declared the wrong global variable, haha!
Just to get back at the part of using the curly braces within quotes, could you explain how that works different from the syntax where I would have variables outside the quotes? `so: "this: {$this}" vs "this ".$this`

Comment: You can use "this: $this" just fine. As well as "this: ".$this. But when it comes to "this->a: $this->a" — it won't work, you'd have to use curly braces, to let it know where your expression ends. The same goes for array index access.

Comment: Could you explain more what `this->a: $this->a` is, I'm not familiar with that syntax. Ive seen it a few times before though

Comment: This is for accessing the member of an object. I'd suggest that you visit php.net if you're going to work with this language (that I can not suggest in my right mind:)).

Comment: Hmmm, I guess I still have a lot to learn. Thanks for all the help, I really appreciate it!